# Spark Studio - background rectangle fills screen proportional to image size

Tags: spark-ar-studio

How do you have a background rectangle (say the one from the cam segmentation example) fill the screen while keeping aspect ratio of the imported image?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using patch editor:

[image: ratio keeper overview]

Image Ratio:

[image: image ratio]

Screen Size:

[image: screen size]

Horizontal Fit:

[image: horizontal fit]

Vertical Fit:

[image: vertical fit]